# WPF Window move flickers on Restriction

Tags: c#, wpf

I have WPF borderless Transparent window.

By using this.DragMove(); I can successfully move the window.

I wanted to restrict window within screen area.
It's also working using below snippet.

```
    private void Window_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                CheckBounds();
    }

private void CheckBounds()
        {
            var height = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
            var width = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;

            if (this.Left < 0)
                this.Left = 0;
            if (this.Top < 0)
                this.Top = 0;
            if (this.Top + this.Height > height)
                this.Top = height - this.Height;
            if (this.Left + this.Width > width)
                this.Left = width - this.Width;
        }
```

But using above code, whenever window reach its max bounds using mouse drag, It starts flickering.

Could anybody suggest how to avoid this flickering?

Comment: This is happening because the window has been moved, and afterwards, it is then relocated by your `CheckBounds` method. [Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/30e0ea0b-84e7-4791-b77e-3d671d33f658/how-to-limit-a-wpf-windows-moveresize-to-desktop-boundaries?forum=wpf) someone has a similar problem.

Comment: Is it possible to avoid the flickering ?

Comment: Maybe instead of moving it back to 0 whenever the window goes out of bounds, you can try and check if the user wants to drag it out and simply not move it.

Comment: As per my requirement, User should not allowed to drag window out of Screen bounds, Thats why I want to restrict user

Comment: Yes, but why don't you just stop moving the window as soon as the user tries to drag it out of bounds?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but you should try to do the opposite of what you do to move it in the first place.

Comment: @DominikB I don't think it's possible to prevent the window from being moved. The flickering is caused by the window being moved, and then immediately relocated. As far as I am aware, I don't think there is a solution to the flickering problem, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @MikeEason He said he used `this.DragMove();` to make the window move. To be fair I never used it but shouldn't it be possible to stop it?

Comment: @DominikB Ah, a fair point. A solution could be to check if the window is *heading* off screen **before** `this.DragMove();` is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I know to deal with this issue is to handle the [`WM_MOVING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632632.aspx) windows message in your window and adjust the position there. Since the `WM_MOVING` message is received before the window actually moves and allows the position to be modified, you never see any jitter. Here is an example code-behind for a `Window`.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private HwndSource mSource;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSourceInitialized(e);

        mSource = (HwndSource)PresentationSource.FromVisual(this);
        mSource.AddHook(WndProc);
    }

    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        mSource.RemoveHook(WndProc);
        mSource.Dispose();
        mSource = null;

        base.OnClosed(e);
    }

    private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        if (msg == (int)WindowsMessage.WM_MOVING)
        {
            // TODO: Substitute realistic bounds
            RECT bounds = new RECT() { Left = 0, Top = 0, Right = 1000, Bottom = 800 };

            RECT window = (RECT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(RECT));
            if (window.Left < bounds.Left)
            {
                window.Right = window.Right + bounds.Left - window.Left;
                window.Left = bounds.Left;
            }
            if (window.Top < bounds.Top)
            {
                window.Bottom = window.Bottom + bounds.Top - window.Top;
                window.Top = bounds.Top;
            }
            if (window.Right >= bounds.Right)
            {
                window.Left = bounds.Right - window.Right + window.Left - 1;
                window.Right = bounds.Right - 1;
            }
            if (window.Bottom >= bounds.Bottom)
            {
                window.Top = bounds.Bottom - window.Bottom + window.Top - 1;
                window.Bottom = bounds.Bottom - 1;
            }
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(window, lParam, true);

            handled = true;
            return new IntPtr(1);
        }

        handled = false;
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
}
```

Here are the helper objects that are used in the code:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct RECT
{
    public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom;
}

enum WindowsMessage
{
    WM_MOVING = 0x0216
}
```

P.S. The `LocationChanged` event (and associated `OnLocationChanged` override) is called in response to [`WM_MOVE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632631.aspx), which is not called until the window has already moved. There does not seem to be a corresponding `OnLocationChanging` event.